# How to convert U+XXX to the actual unicode character (in the native script)

Tags: python, unicode, codepoint

I have a list of code points (U+XXXX) that I need to convert into real characters. My code points are for UTF-8. I've scoured the previous mentions of unicode and don't see how to do that.

I can strip U+XXXX to get the number (XXXX), but then what? Some have suggested "unichr()" but that is not even recognized in Python3.

Sorry if this is basic; just started programming in Python.

Comment: UTF-8 does not have code points.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.x doesn't have `unichr()` because Python 3.x supports Unicode strings natively.

```
3>> chr(int('3042', 16))
'あ'
```

Answer (score 0):

unichr() is replaced by chr() in python3,
you can convert strings like 'U+XXXX' to characters like this:

```
chr(int('U+XXXX'.lstrip('U+'), 16))
```